# Mapping an Array of custom objects using fluent nhibernate

Tags: collections, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two classes, File and SearchResults. ShearchResults has an array of files. The relation between them is ManyToMany. This is how i mapped the relationship:

```
HasManyToMany<File>(x => x.Files).Table("refSearchResultsFiles").ParentKeyColumn("[SearchResult]").ChildKeyColumn("[File]");
```

When i try to save a SearchResult object, i get this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag' to type 'TankusFileSharingClassLibrary.Entities.File[]'.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `.AsArray(...)` in the hasmanytomany